# Set group ownership on FTP upload via an ACL

Tags: linux, permissions, acl, vsftpd

I am interested in setting an ACL which will chown all the files I upload through FTP to the `www-data` group.

However, after performing

```
chown -R user:www-data /var/www/website.com/public_html/
setfacl -dRm g:www-data:rwx /var/www/scwist.ca/public_html/
```

every file that I upload through the FTP isn't assigned to the `www-data` group but assigns the files to the user who uploaded the files.

What command should I be entering?

Answer (score 1):

Use `chmod g+s public_html` to make new files created in the directory [inherit](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html) the group of the directory. You don't need ACLs to achieve that, although you may want to use them for other reasons.

Strictly, this behaviour is filesystem- and platform-specific, but it works under Linux for common filesystems. It is commonly supported elsewhere too.